# How to write sub queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am joining three tables and taking count [MY SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e34392/25). In this query I want to take one more count like `total_trip` that means I already join the `trip_details` table, in this table take all count that is total trip count, I am not able to write sub query.

```
SELECT COUNT(T.tripId) as Escort_Count,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (
        SELECT a.allocationId
        FROM escort_allocation a 
        INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
        WHERE c.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip' 
        GROUP BY a.allocationId
    ) AS Ad

) AS Adhoc_Trip_Count 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT a.tripId FROM 
    trip_details a 
    INNER JOIN 
    escort_allocation b 
    ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
    GROUP BY a.allocationId 
) AS T
```

Comment: What exactly do you want your query to do? It's not clear from your statement, *i want to take one more count like `total_trip` that means i already join `trip_details` tables, in this table take all count that is total trip count*.

Comment: What is desired result?

Comment: @ lurker. check my [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25879b/1)  . from here i am getting two results like `Escort_Count` and `Adhoc_Trip_Count`,Now i want to take one more result is `total_trip`, total_trip means we have to take count * from `trip_details` table

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas, Escort_Count:`5` and Adhoc_Trip_Count:`2` and total_trip : `7`

Comment: update your question (not comment)  add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery in following:

---

**Query:**

```
  SELECT COUNT(T.tripId) as Escort_Count,
  (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
      (
          SELECT a.allocationId
          FROM escort_allocation a 
          INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
          WHERE c.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip' 
          GROUP BY a.allocationId
      ) AS Ad

  ) AS Adhoc_Trip_Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM trip_details) as Total_Count
  FROM 
  ( 
      SELECT a.tripId FROM 
      trip_details a 
      INNER JOIN 
      escort_allocation b 
      ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
      GROUP BY a.allocationId 
  ) AS T
```

---

**Results:**

```
Escort_Count   Adhoc_Trip_Count   Total_Trip
5              2                  7
```

---

**Check it out:**

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25879b/9)</kbd>

Comment: I tried your query it is not working properly like i changed `cab_allocation`  table previously two `Adhoc Trip` happened,Now i changed `3`, now result should come `Escort_Count: 5` and `Adhoc_Trip_Count:3` and `Total_Trip: 7` but i am not getting my expected result [see your SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57986a/1)

Comment: @KaniR so 5 + 3 = 8, not 7... Why `Total_Trip` should be `7`?

Comment: Total_Trip means we have to take the count(*) FROM trip_details , no need sum of `Escort_Count + Adhoc_Trip_Count`

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas, Your fiddle working fine, i want to add one more condition like `trip_details` table i added one more column called `tripDate`, i have to take above results only on today records,**main thing we have to use between condition in ** `tripDate` column and `trip_details` table kindly update your fiddle please

Comment: @KaniR ask another question for this.

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas, Possible means update this question only because again i have to wait for 90 Minutes to post new question

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas,i posted new question what i asked like between condition kindly update your answer [New question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434096/ho-to-use-between-condition-using-using-main-query-and-sub-quries?noredirect=1#comment85870244_49434096
)

Comment: @ Stanislovas Kalašnikovas,are you there please update your answer, i am waiting for your replay

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Z.allocationId) Escort_Count,SUM(CASE WHEN allocationType='Adhoc Trip' THEN 1 END) Adhoc_Trip_Count  FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT a.allocationId, allocationType FROM escort_allocation a 
           INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
           INNER JOIN trip_details TD ON a.allocationId = TD.allocationId 
           GROUP BY a.allocationId
        )Z;
```

**`OR`**

```
SELECT Escort_Count,Adhoc_Trip_Count,Adhoc_Trip_Count+Escort_Count TOTAL FROM(
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Z.allocationId) Escort_Count,SUM(CASE WHEN allocationType='Adhoc Trip' THEN 1 END) Adhoc_Trip_Count,COUNT(D)  FROM (
               SELECT DISTINCT a.allocationId, allocationType,SUM(1) D FROM escort_allocation a 
               INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
               INNER JOIN trip_details TD ON a.allocationId = TD.allocationId 
               GROUP BY a.allocationId
            )Z
        )ZZ;
```

You can try above query .

Definitely it will help you.

Comment: Ya, it is working fine, but where is `totatrip_count`, we have to take from trip_details table

Comment: TOTAL means we have to take the count(*) FROM trip_details , no need sum of Escort_Count + Adhoc_Trip_Count

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT td.tripId, COUNT(*) as total, SUM(ea.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip') as adhocs
FROM trip_details td JOIN
     escort_allocation ea
     ON td.allocationId = ea.allocationId 
GROUP BY td.tripId;
```

Comment: I tried your query it shows the following Error: `Unknown column 'c.allocationType' in 'field list'`

Comment: LOL - I wonder how long it would take to write an application by posting questions on SO and pasting the answers into a text editor.

Comment: @ Nishant Gupta [Check My Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25879b/1).from here i am getting two results like Escort_Count and Adhoc_Trip_Count,Now i want to take one more result is total_trip, total_trip means we have to take count * from trip_details table