# How to use between condition using main query and sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i am using `JOIN` in 3 tables and getting the count.

1. trip_details
2. escort_allocation
3. cab_allocation

---

`cab_allocation` i am taking Total_Count and `escort_allocation` i am taking Escort_Count like **trip_details** allocationId i am using forien key escort_allocation using inner join i am taking count.**Adhoc_Trip_Count** i am taking from `trip_details` and `cab_allocation`.*trip_details allocationId i am using forien key cab_allocation* using this i am taking count ,my query is working perfect.***Now my question is i want to add BETWEEN in two dates***.in trip_details table i have one column called `tripDate`.suppose i am giving dates like `2018-03-20` INTO `2018-03-23` means , i want fetch records between this two dates

> MYSQL QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT(T.tripId) as Escort_Count,
  (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
      (
          SELECT a.allocationId
          FROM escort_allocation a 
          INNER JOIN cab_allocation c ON a.allocationId = c.allocationId 
          WHERE c.allocationType = 'Adhoc Trip' 
          GROUP BY a.allocationId
      ) AS Ad

  ) AS Adhoc_Trip_Count,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM trip_details) as Total_Count
  FROM 
  ( 
      SELECT a.tripId FROM 
      trip_details a 
      INNER JOIN 
      escort_allocation b 
      ON a.allocationId = b.allocationId 
      GROUP BY a.allocationId 
  ) AS T
```

[***SQL FIDDLE***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/081f39/1)

Comment: add the date column to the table add some data into that column, then tell us what the expected result should be. You have 2 subqueries referencing trip_details, should both be affected by the date range? your question isn't clear enough to answer well.

Comment: This looks like the exact same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434096/how-to-use-between-condition-using-using-main-query-and-sub-queries